# Question about a bounded sequence in $W^{1,1}$ admitting a weakly convergent subsequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{12}$ and $f_n\in L^7(B)$ such that $\lVert f_n \rVert_{W^{1,4}(B)}$ is bounded. Is it true that
there exists a subsequence weakly convergent in $W^{1,1}(B)$?

My guess is it doesn't exist. Since the domain is bounded then $f_n$ is also bounded in $W^{1,1}$ which is not reflexive. But i'm having trouble finding a counterexample.
I tried $f_n(x)=|x|^{-12/7+1/n}$. It satisfies the assumptions but does it admit a weakly convergent subsequence in $W^{1,1}(B)$?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(f_n)$ is bounded in $W^{1,4}$, then it has a subsequence converging weakly in $W^{1,4}$. This sequence also converges weakly in $W^{1,1}$, due to the continuity of the embedding $W^{1,4}\hookrightarrow W^{1,1}$.

Comment: I see, thank you. What about weak convergence of a subsequence in $L^7$? Sobolev embedding only gives immersion up to $L^6$..

Comment: If  $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L^7$, then you get also subsequential weak convergence in $L^7$.

Comment: I meant with the previuous hypothesis, so that $f_n\in L^7$ and bounded in $W^{1,4}$, but not necessarily bounded in $L^7$

Comment: There is a weakly convergent sequence in $L^7$ if and only if there is a bounded subsequence in $L^7$.

Comment: thank you, it was easier than i thought!